# How to include service automatically using Node and Express.js

Tags: node.js

My ./controller/index.js look like below

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use('/api/user/session', require('./authentication.controller'));
    app.use('/api/users', require('./users.controller.js'));
    app.use('/api/roles', require('./roles.controller.js'));
    app.use('/api/tenants', require('./tenants.controller.js'));
}
```

under controller I have

```
└── controllers
    ├── users.controller.js
    ├── roles.controller.js
    └── authentication.controller.js
```

my problem if i am add any new file under /controller folder it should dynamically add in controller/index.js

for example if am add permission.js under controller folder my controller/index.js file should become like bellow.

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.use('/api/user/session', require('./authentication.controller'));
    app.use('/api/users', require('./users.controller.js'));
    app.use('/api/roles', require('./roles.controller.js'));
    app.use('/api/tenants', require('./tenants.controller.js'));
    app.use('/api/permission', require('./permission.controller.js'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index.js file in the controller folder that does the following:

**./controllers/index.js**

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');


//load all routes in dir
module.exports = function (server) {
  fs
      .readdirSync(__dirname)
      .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== -1) && (file !== "index.js");
      })
      .forEach(function (file) {
        file = file.split('.')[0];
        server.use('/api/' + file, require(path.join(__dirname, file));
      });
};
```

**app.js**

```
//load all controllers and routes
require('.controllers')(server)
```

Comment: @PJohnRaj let me know if you ran into trouble, I use this pattern alote